# Web Notification Push Subscription what to do with auth?

Tags: web-notifications

A Web Notification subscription post back might give this data:

```
{
    "customerid": "123456",
    "subscription": {
        "endpoint": "https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/v1/gAAAA…",
        "keys": {
            "p256dh": "BOrnIslXrUow2VAzKCUAE4sIbK00daEZCswOcf8m3TF8V…",
            "auth": "k8JV6sjdbhAi1n3_LDBLvA"
         }
    },
    "favoritedrink": "warm milk"
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something because I don't know what to do with the auth data (`k8JV6sjdbhAi1n3_LDBLvA`), how does it get used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what to do by using this library: https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-csharp

Nuget

```
Install-Package WebPush



public static string Encode(byte[] data)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(data).Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_').TrimEnd('=');
        }

     public static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair GenerateKeys()
            {
                var ecParameters = NistNamedCurves.GetByName("P-256");
                var ecSpec = new ECDomainParameters(ecParameters.Curve, ecParameters.G, ecParameters.N, ecParameters.H,
                    ecParameters.GetSeed());
                var keyPairGenerator = GeneratorUtilities.GetKeyPairGenerator("ECDH");
                keyPairGenerator.Init(new ECKeyGenerationParameters(ecSpec, new SecureRandom()));

                return keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
            }

public string privateKeyStr;
public string publicKeyStr;

public void DoWork()
{
  byte[] publicKey = ((ECPublicKeyParameters)keys.Public).Q.GetEncoded(false);
            byte[] privateKey = ((ECPrivateKeyParameters)keys.Private).D.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
            privateKeyStr = Encode(privateKey);
            publicKeyStr = Encode(publicKey);

// Save/Restore privateKeyStr / publicKeyStr (don't want to gen each time)

// now publicKeyStr needs to be an input into the ServiceWoker reg in javascript
```

eg

```
const serviceWorker = navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceworkerloader.js', { scope: './' }).then(
    function (swReg) {
        console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);
        swRegistration = swReg;

        swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
            .then(function (subscription) {
                let isSubscribed = !(subscription === null)

                if (isSubscribed) {
                    console.log('User IS subscribed.')

                    let unsub = false
                    if (unsub) {
                        subscription.unsubscribe()
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('User is NOT subscribed.')
                }
            });

        // subscribe
        const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey);
        swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
            userVisibleOnly: true,
            applicationServerKey: applicationServerKey
        }).then(function (subscription) {
            updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);
            isSubscribed = true
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Failed to subscribe the user: ', err);
        });

    })
```

This returns data like this:

```
{
    "customerid": "123456",
    "subscription": {
        "endpoint": "https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/v1/gAAAA…",
        "keys": {
            "p256dh": "BOrnIslXrUow2VAzKCUAE4sIbK00daEZCswOcf8m3TF8V…",
            "auth": "k8JV6sjdbhAi1n3_LDBLvA"
         }
    },
    "favoritedrink": "warm milk"
}
```

Which must make it back to your server then you can run this code:

```
    var pushEndpoint = @"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/clKG12Pq-vQ:APA91bGvMOg0lgnAiHvN6X8AOh0hVN5KsGrdXNC9zka0uIbZUTbbypcd5Ns7pamt2tQcKvedZVm_i7tW996wN82pnx4ks1dH022cPm_GDLW0SsHwwLtvGgWGJ1grANp04GuwiNZQ9rhpb2X8FsjqIYL499Q49LydRg";
    var p256dh = @"BDSRQDB8Okr85gC7V4YMQEHsEMxBjOoN1GTdsnL9CcyZ_xrvna1u1AV9yoYBWZ80dNKzeMSqWhybMGvFkPuDq6s";
    var auth = @"oKospnY_RDj_EiRsn-PwuA";

    var subject = @"mailto:example@example.com";
    var publicKey = generatedPublicKey;
    //@"BDjASz8kkVBQJgWcD05uX3VxIs_gSHyuS023jnBoHBgUbg8zIJvTSQytR8MP4Z3-kzcGNVnM...............";
    var privateKey = generatedPrivateKey;
        //@"mryM-krWj_6IsIMGsd8wNFXGBxnx...............";

    var subscription = new PushSubscription(pushEndpoint, p256dh, auth);
    var vapidDetails = new VapidDetails(subject, publicKey, privateKey);
    //var gcmAPIKey = @"[your key here]";

    var webPushClient = new WebPushClient();
    try
    {
        webPushClient.SendNotification(subscription, "payload", vapidDetails);
        //webPushClient.SendNotification(subscription, "payload", gcmAPIKey);
    }
    catch (WebPushException exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Http STATUS code" + exception.StatusCode);
    }
```